# How can I turn off the “allow automatic updating” for **all** apps?

Tags: google-play-store, 2.3-gingerbread, updates, application-autoupdate

Recently Google started to check the “allow automatic updating” for their apps without being asked, which I hate. I have to deactivate it for each app separately.

But more importantly this pushed Google Books onto my phone, which I don´t need and wastes precious 4 MB internal memory.

And here comes the nasty twist: Google book is not actually available for my System (for whatever reason). So I can´t get the applications market page to un-check the “allow automatic updating”.

This leaves me wondering: is there a way to deactivate the “allow automatic updating” for **all** applications?

Comment: Automatic updating, as well as Google's backup service, has never worked on my phone at all.  If I find out why and it's something you can turn on and off, I'll let you know!

Comment: @Matthew Read, I think it may be because of TouchWiz. Once I installed CyanogenMod, it pulled down all my apps from the market and installed them, and I wish it didn't, I have a lot installed :), it locked up my phone for a while.

Comment: There used to be an app available on XDA Forums that allowed a root user to bulk toggle auto update on/off for all apps. However, a recent Market update has broken functionality.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There bitter truth is there is none option to switch all automatic updated off in one go.

I solved my particular problem by rooting the phone. Since no exploit is known for 2.3.4 I had to unlock the phone. This in turn meant that both *Amazon MP3* and *Google Books* stopped updating themselves.

Which is one way to solve the problem. Still I removed the files using the following Script:

```
#!/opt/local/bin/zsh

setopt No_Err_Exit

adb -d uninstall com.amazon.mp3
adb -d uninstall com.google.android.apps.books

setopt Err_Exit

adb -d pull /system/app/com.amazon.mp3.apk Originals/com.amazon.mp3.apk
adb -d pull /system/app/BooksPhone.apk     Originals/BooksPhone.apk
adb -d pull /system/app/BooksPhone.odex    Originals/BooksPhone.odex

adb -d shell <<-EOF
    su
    mount -o remount,rw /dev/block/mtdblock3 /system

    busybox rm -v /system/app/com.amazon.mp3.apk
    busybox rm -v /system/app/BooksPhone.apk
    busybox rm -v /system/app/BooksPhone.odex

    mount -o remount,ro /dev/block/mtdblock3 /system

    busybox rm -v    /data/dalvik-cache/system@app@com.amazon.mp3.apk@classes.dex
    busybox rm -v -r /data/data/com.amazon.mp3
    busybox rm -v -r /data/data/com.google.android.apps.books

    exit
    exit
EOF

# vim: set nowrap tabstop=4 shiftwidth=4 softtabstop=4 noexpandtab :
# vim: -d set textwidth=0 filetype=zsh foldmethod=marker nospell :
```

**Warning:** This is script from the *“If you can't understand it you should not be using it”* category.

Comment: +1 Why you use `uninstall` command? To remove updates or proper deregistering? Isn't `busybox rm` enough? Is it possible to use `disable` instead?

Answer (score 8):

Market version 3.3.11 now has a setting called "Auto-update apps". Enabling it will effectively set each individual app associated with the account to auto-update, and disabling it will of course do the opposite. This setting is found by simply going into the Market's settings (`Menu Button->Settings` on phones, or use the top-right action bar on Honeycomb).

You can read about the release [here](http://www.androidpolice.com/2011/11/01/download-android-market-3-3-11-adds-new-settings-default-auto-update-update-over-wi-fi-only-shortcuts-and-more/). It also has links that could help you sideload the update if it is not automatically available to you.

Answer (score 3):

You could use a program like [Droidwall](http://code.google.com/p/droidwall/) to block Market's internet access, this should keep it from installing/uninstalling programs.

Answer (score 2):

If you have Titanium Backup installed you could try and Freeze the program **Software Update**.

Comment: Good thinking, but for Titanium Backup the phone needs to be rooted. And once you did that you have an even cooler way to solve the problem: `adb shell su rm /system/app/BooksPhone.apk` ;-) — Don't forget to make a backup copy fist just in case Google manages a 2.3.5 release.

Comment: This highlights that on most phones, the space used in /system isn't space that a user can normally use, anyway. So the 4 MB is actually zero impact.

Answer (score 2):

Titanium Backup (root only) has "Market Tools". One of these tools is "Market Auto Updates" which presents a list of all your apps with their checkboxes for auto-updates. You can sort the enabled apps to the top, and you can "deselect all" to disable automatic updating for all apps.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the trick:

1. Use an app manager to force stop the Play Store, then clear all the data.
2. Go to the Play Store's settings, then deselect "Auto update apps by default"

Comment: Why do you have to force close it?

Answer (score -3):

When in android market select my apps. u will see all the applications installed. select tha one u want to disable automatic updates. u will see a small checkbox at the bottom. uncheck it.

Comment: Which part of **»So I can't get the applications market page to un-check the “allow automatic updating”.«** did you not understand?
—
And in the question title is one word marked with double stars. I did that because I thought this is the most important aspect of my question. Something to distinguished my Question from similar questions.
—
**Anyway, welcome to stack overflow.**
—
Hint: Wait until your answer is at -3 then delete it to get the “peer pressure” honour batch.